# Getting Flow information from RYU controller

Tags: openflow

I need to get the following information about a flow for my application.

- FLOW_ID
- MATCHED_SRC_MAC
- DST_PORT
- SRC_SWITCH
- DST_SWITCH
- FLOW_PATH_FLAGS
- MATCH_DST_MAC
- SRC_PORT
- TYPE
- INSTALLED
- DATA_PATH_SUMMARY
- USER_STATE.

Can I get these information by

1) Importing some imodule in RYU

2) Sending some message to the RYU and listening to the reply

3) Some other means?

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is still up to date but have you taken a look at the [ofctl_rest](http://ryu.readthedocs.org/en/latest/app/ofctl_rest.html) api?

With a call to `http://localhost:8080/stats/flow/<dpid>` you can get some flow information. I think you won't get everything you need but it's a start.

```
Attribute       Description                             Example
dpid            Datapath                                ID  “1”
length          Length of this entry                    88
table_id        Table ID                                0
duration_sec    Time flow has been alive in seconds     2
duration_nsec   Time flow has been alive in nanoseconds 6.76e+08
priority        Priority of the entry                   11111
idle_timeout    Number of seconds idle before expiration    0
hard_timeout    Number of seconds before expiration     0
flags           Bitmap of OFPFF_* flags                 1
cookie          Opaque controller-issued identifier     1
packet_count    Number of packets in flow               0
byte_count      Number of bytes in flow                 0
match           Fields to match                         {“in_port”: 1}
actions         Instruction set                         [“OUTPUT:2”]
```